# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name:index

Tags: c#

[image]

[image]

This was working befor but its stopped and i don't know why this message just keeps coming up:

ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name:index

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post code, not images, please!

Comment: Also: "This was working befor but its stopped" - we don't even know how it looked like before. You do. So what changes did you make between "working" and "not working"? It's highly likely, that (one of?) these changes caused the problem. Again, you know better than anyone here, what you did. Retrace what you did, step by step, to find where exactly it stopped working.

Comment: sorry I'm new to this n I've been up all night trying to fix my code as my game needs to be handed in today and with this code not working there are no enemies spawning

Comment: i have made no changes just updated unity

Comment: What I'm getting at is, that code doesn't just suddenly stop working. So *something* must have happened, but you didn't tell us, what. You might want to include something like the unity update in future questions. Although, it's highly unlikely, that that was the cause. Unless you updated to a really unstable developer version. Problems pointed out in the given answer or the linked duplicates are far more likely to be the cause. -- Also, important life lesson: don't update dependencies or make big changes the day before something needs to be handed in. ^_^;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, you're not populating the list `SpawnPrefabs` or, at least, not populating it enough to have an element at one of the indexes that you're referencing.